# Proving that this cone is a limit cone

Tags: category-theory, limits-colimits, functors

Let $D:I\to[\mathscr A,\mathscr C]$ be a diagram, and $ev_A:[\mathscr A,\mathscr C]\to \mathscr C$ the evaluation-at-$A$ functor. Let $L:\mathscr A\to \mathscr C$ be the functor such that $L(A)$ is the vertex of the limit cone of $ev_A\circ D=D(-)(A)$. There's a cone $(p_i:L\to D(I))_{i\in I}$ on $D$ in $[\mathscr A,\mathscr C]$, where $p_i$ is the natural transformation whose component at $A$, $p_{i,A}$, is the projection from the limit $L(A)$ to $D(i)(A)$.

I'm trying to prove that this cone $(p_i)_{i\in I}$ is a limit cone. Given another cone $(f_i:K\to D(i))_{i\in I}$, I can define $\kappa:K\to L$ as follows: the $A$th component of the natural transformation $\kappa$ is the unique map from $ev_A(K)=K(A)$ to the limit $L(A)$.

But I'm having difficulties with showing that $\kappa$ forms a natural transformation. I need to show that for any $s:A\to A'$, one has $\kappa_{A'}\circ K(s)=L(s) \circ \kappa_A$. How to do that? I looked at my old notes, and there I followed both arrows by $p_{i,A'}$ and claimed that the triple compositions are equal (and after that deduced that the double compositions are equal). But I don't see now why the triple compositions are equal.

---

Addition: $\mathscr C$ is assumed to have limits of shape $I$ (or at least the diagram $D(-)(A)$ is assumed to have a limit). Also I guess $\mathscr A$ and $I$ are assumed to be small and $\mathscr C$ is assumed to be locally small.

Comment: The claim is false in that generality, isn't it? You need some additional hypothesis, e.g. $\mathcal{C}$ has limits of shape $\mathcal{I}$, or $\textrm{ev}_A$ has a left adjoint.

Comment: Oops, I guess that's right, I've added some assumptions.

Comment: If you are assuming that $\mathcal{C}$ has limits of all diagrams of shape $\mathcal{I}$ then you need a different argument: first you construct limits of diagrams of shape $\mathcal{I}$ in $[\mathcal{A}, \mathcal{C}]$ explicitly in terms of limits in $\mathcal{C}$.

Comment: @ZhenLin I believe I tried to sketch Leinster's proof of Theorem 6.2.5 in the text of this question. For the proof of the fact I'm asking about he refers to Lemma 6.1.3(b); I just wanted a direct proof because I understand neither how 6.1.3(b) is applied here, nor the proof of 6.1.3(b) (probably I got lost in the details but I don't see the big picture).

Comment: Huh? The proof of theorem 6.2.5 goes exactly as I said: it constructs the limit in $[\mathcal{A}, \mathcal{C}]$ explicitly in terms of limits in $\mathcal{C}$. To check that an "arbitrary" limit cone is preserved by the evaluation functor you use the uniqueness of limit cones to reduce to the case of the explicitly constructed one.

Comment: @ZhenLin Isn't what I'm doing in the question the same as you and Leinster say? The limit cone $(p_i)$ in the functor category is defined in terms of the limit cone $(p_{i,A})$ in $\mathscr C$.

Comment: Hmmm. It looks like I misread your question. The triple compositions are equal because of how you defined $\kappa_{A'}$ and $L (s)$.